# How to avoid the warning "Redundant constraint: Functor f" in the getter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have some record `SomeRecord` and fields like `_user`, `_password`. And I want to write a `Getter` for a "virtual" field, like identity which will look like `<user>:<password>`:

```hs
identity:: Getter SomeRecord String
identity = to $ \srec -> srec^.user <> ":" <> srec^.password
```

and this getter leads to the warning:

```
• Redundant constraint: Functor f
• In the type signature for:
       identity :: Getter SomeRecord Stringtypecheck(-Wredundant-constraints)
```

what's wrong with this getter and how to write it without warnings?

**EDIT:**

Just found [this thread](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/12142) in the Web:

> Comment (by ekmett):
>
> In the interest of not getting drowned in complaints by the users of
> `lens` on GHC 8, we'll likely just add the constraint to `to` and rely
> on `{-# INLINE #-}` dropping it out in practice. This is a common
> enough scenario to warrant us eating the noise on our side.
>
> Of course, you'll get the same sort of thing if you go to declare a
> non- law abiding traversal as a fold, etc. There i'm afraid the only
> answer will be to squelch the warning. GHC can't see 'laws'.

Comment: Please share the full exception.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem done (not exception, just a compiling warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way that Edward Kmett's lens library works.

`Getter` is a type synonym:

```
type Getter s a = forall f. (Contravariant f, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

Meanwhile the type of `to` is:

```
to :: (Profunctor p, Contravariant f) => (s -> a) -> Optic' p f s a
```

Never mind the `Optic'`, the problem is that `Getter` has the constraint `Functor f` but the `to` doesn't need it. Hence the warning, because otherwise you could use it with a type `f` that isn't a functor.

The "proper" type for your function is something like:

```
identity :: (Profunctor p, Contravariant f) => Optic' p f SomeRecord String
```